# intent bundle variables not being passed between activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bundle, oncreate

in `mActivity.this` I set up an intent and a bundle

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity.this, nextActivity.class);
        Bundle mBundleNow = new Bundle();
        mBundleNow.putString("formattedAddress", formattedAddress);
        mBundleNow.putDouble("latitude", latitude);
        mBundleNow.putDouble("longitude", longitude);
        mBundleNow.putString("newRequest", ""); //should probably be bool
        intent.putExtras(mBundleNow);
```

when I run `startActivity(intent)` the intent and the bundle map are populated.

in the `onCreate` method of `nextActivity.class` , `getIntent().getExtras()` is not null, but there is no map, none of the variables I set are there.

How is this happening? and how can I get my intent variables to be included properly

Comment: Please post the onCreate() method for nextactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead the bundle, try this:

```
intent.putExtra("varName", varValue);
```

Comment: getIntent().getExtras() map is still null and therefore has none of my variables

Comment: In your original post you said "getIntent().getExtras() is not null". Which is true?

Comment: @MikeM. it is not null. getExtras() contains a map, the map is null which means no key/values pairs that I set are there

Comment: Also, using the suggestion of @William Bertan, you would use the getStringExtra() and getDoubleExtra() methods when retrieving values attached with the putExtra() method.

Comment: getExtras() returns a Bundle. With that Bundle, you would use the getString() and getDouble() methods. If you will post your onCreate() method, we can get you sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

Using your **exact bundle data** line for line, I successfully retrieved the latitude using:

```
double myLat = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("latitude");

Log.d("Lat is: ", ": " + String.valueOf(myLat));
```

Try this code exactly in the onCreate of NextActivity, and if it doesn't work, something else is going haywire, not the passing of extras because it works here fine.

*Try posting the code of your onCreate of NextActivity if this doesn't work for you and I will edit my answer to reflect the new information*

Comment: yes, something else is going haywire, do you know what the possibilities are? maybe a flag on the activity in the manifest that can alter things?

Comment: @CQM are you sure the data you're putting in, aka latitude, definately has data in it? Try a hardcoded value (i tried 2.2)